# How do I protect The End using Worldguard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldguard

I am a moderator on an SMP server.  We have a Bukkit plugin called WorldGuard that we use to set protected plots and disable PvP in certain areas.  Can WorldGuard be used to do the same thing in the End?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I never made regions in The End myself, The End works much in the same way as any other world. There's no reason why it can't work that way.

People used to make all sorts on my servers version of The End and we had it set up so people would have to get their items when they were at The End (rather than walk in with them). As such, you should be able to use WorldGuard for regions.

I hope this helps, please do let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Tim.  This has been confirmed by other server staff too.  For some reason, we have decided to forgo using Worldguard in the End. 

Why was the server that you reference set up so that people had to get their items while in the End?

Comment: Just to make it a bit different, really: It was treated more like an "arena" event of kinds. You had to run in with no gear and fight off Endermen (and other enemies that were thrown into the fray) and get to some chests plonked around the area. Open a chest, get an item, it could be taken back to other worlds (Some enchanted items). The enemies dropped gold, too. People seemed to like the event, but it wasn't automated, just set up by the admins.

I've sinced moved on from that, but it was just another way to play :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work. If you want to protect the entire End, I would simply go out beyond the edges of the land. If you *really* don't want people to build anywhere, disable building with a [flag](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Regions/Flags).